# How to delete hidden files from a vector of file names?

Tags: c++, file, vector, hidden

In a program that I am writing, there is a function that takes all of the filenames from a specific directory and puts them into a vector so they can be used later in the program.

However, this also grabs any hidden files that happen to be in the folder. I've tried to just have the program delete any files starting with a '.', but that has not worked on the folder that I was testing (I still get ".." listed as a file).

***Here is the section of the code:***

```
while (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
     filenameList.push_back(search_data.cFileName);

    if (FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}

    //removes a lot of hidden files from the file list
    for (int i = 0; i < filenameList.size(); i++)
    {
        string hiddenCheck = filenameList[i];

        if (hiddenCheck[0] == '.') 
        {
            filenameList.erase(filenameList.begin() + i);
            i = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, i. e. checking whether the detection or the erasure does not work?

Comment: `I still get ".." listed as a file` That´s not a hidden file, and it´s expected behaviour. Just filter ".." out by yourself (as well as ".") (no, I don´t mean anything starting with a point, but only the point itself)

Comment: The hidden files that I'm talking about all begin with '.', like ".thumbs", ".dsstore", or ".bridge". I've tried various ways of searching for the dot at the beginning of the filename, like using a char variable to search instead of a string, but none will delete all of the hidden files.

Comment: Rather than stuffing the hidden files into the vector and then taking them out, why not test sooner and not put them in in the first place? Also consider what happens to the for loop's exit condition if you remove the last item from the list.  Look into the [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) while you're at it.

Comment: As someone else said already the point in the filename doesn´t make anything hidden in Windows...

Comment: Looked a bit deeper and see you're defending yourself from outrunning the end of the vector by restarting the search of the vector every time you remove an element. That's a pretty expensive solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the file attributes while you are enumerating the files:

```
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(..., &search_data);
if (handle != NULL)
{
    do
    {
        // if not a directory, and not hidden...
        if ((search_data.dwFileAttributes & (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)) == 0)
        {
            // add it to the list...
            filenameList.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(handle, &search_data));
    FindClose(handle);
}
```

Comment: Fyi for the OP, this will exclude *all* folder names (i.e. subfolders), not just ones starting with `'.'`. If you want to keep subdir folders, excluding only aliases for `.` and `..`, this will still need to be tweaked.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't think the OP needs to worry about that, considering the original code was not even handling subfolders to begin with. The OP's description does say he only wanted filenames and nothing about recursing into subfolders.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not handling subfolders. From the looks of that   `push_back`, *everything* returned from the FindFirst/FindNext loop was being shoved into the container, subdir names included. If I inferred this will not *recurse* into subfolders, that was not my intention. I was simply stating *immediate* subdir folder names will simply not be included in the list. That was all. Sorry if that wasn't clear.